# Which parameter has the most impact on result in apache OLSMultipleLinearRegression

Tags: java, linear-regression, apache-commons-math

I'm experimenting with OLSMultipleLinearRegression and I wonder which of my parameters has most impact on the prediction. I do not understand which method in OLSMultipleLinearRegression that will return that information.

```
static void test() {
    double y[] = {110, 120, 135, 140};
    double data[][] = {
            {9, 100},
            {21, 260},
            {29, 490},
            {41, 650}
    };

    OLSMultipleLinearRegression regression = new OLSMultipleLinearRegression();
    regression.newSampleData(y, data);

    double[] beta = regression.estimateRegressionParameters();

    for(int i = 0;i<beta.length;i++) {
        System.out.printf("b%d = %.3f\n",i, beta[i]);
    }

    int ROW = 3;
    double value = y[ROW];
    double predict = beta[0] + beta[1] * data[ROW][0] + beta[2] * data[ROW][1];

    System.out.printf("y=%.3f + %.3f * %.3f + %.3f * %.3f\n", beta[0],beta[1],data[ROW][0],beta[2],data[ROW][1]);
    System.out.printf("predict=%.3f value=%.3f\n", predict, value );
}
```